# If I drive a car/van/truck off a cliff, will it explode?

Tags: just-cause-2

Frequently to get away from the police, I find myself making a clever and subtle escape off a nearby cliff using a hijacked car/truck/van. When I hit the ground after the fall, my vehicle is pretty banged up, but it doesn't usually explode. This makes me wonder, **is there a maximum height I can fall before I blow up?**

*<sup>Fun fact: This does not apply to motorcycles</sup>*

Comment: I remember playing this game...Are you sure the height of said jump is high enough? My guess is that the amount of damage a plane has to recieve before it blows up is a very small amount of damage compared to a car/truck/van. As you point out a motorcycle has no problem blowing up.  Any vechicle that blows up is based on how much damage it recieved, each type would be a different amount, only real explaination.

Comment: It's off the cliff near the Repear's Mountain Base, near the center of the map

Comment: I agree with Ramhound. I don't think there's really a "fall distance" that causes it to explode. I think the vehicles just take damage from hitting the ground, and if that damage causes the total to exceed the vehicles limit, it explodes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends.  Vehicle 'explosion' damage is calculated... strangely, in Just Cause 2.  More likely than not, your car would be fine at the bottom.  When you're IN a vehicle, it becomes much more resistant to damage (with the exception of planes, which become less resistant).  Have you noticed that jumping out of a moving vehicle tends to cause it to explode when it hits *anything*, even if it's going very slowly?

In any case, I *have* had vehicles *catch fire* and even explode on very rare occasion after long drops **with me still inside**, but in most of those cases, the vehicle was already damaged.  I've driven off of that particular cliff hundreds of times, and almost always make it to the bottom intact.

---

If I had to pick something to give as an *answer*, I'd say that you're much more likely to explode if you land directly (with all four wheels) on a **flat surface** from a pretty substantial height.  Let me explain why I think this is:

Vehicle *damage* and vehicle *instant explosion* appear to behave as two completely different things, to me.  Vehicles appear to actually fall pretty slowly, and not accelerate, but I think there's a game 'value' or something for impact that keeps increasing as you fall, to a point.  However, I get the impression that this 'value' only affects the vehicles *instant explosion*, and the actual falling speed is what affects vehicle *damage*.  So, if you fall from a great height, but not quite great enough for the instant explosion to be triggered, your vehicle will only receive a (relatively slight) amount of damage.

Have you tried driving a vehicle off a cliff so that it rolls down, bouncing against the cliff face on the way down?  This almost always destroys your vehicle before reaching the bottom (on a good sized cliff) by causing too much damage to it, **NOT** by causing it to explode instantly.  Since the vehicle is in more contact with the hillside on the way down than it would be if you didn't touch until you hit the bottom, the vehicle suffers more damage, even though, logically, it should be falling so fast as to be utterly obliterated in the latter scenario.

(I'm not sure how *accurate* this stuff about falling 'values' is, but it's the best way I can think of to explain it right now.  This is drawing from my hundreds of hours of game play time.  I can tell you right now that **however** this system works, it's extremely inconsistent.  Vehicles seem to arbitrarily explode in *any* situation.)

The reason this 'doesn't apply to motorbikes', as you say, is because the only time you ever land a motorbike with you still on it is on a flat surface: otherwise you always fall off, and the bike then becomes susceptible to imminent explosion.  This also means it *does* apply to boats.

Try this: hit the gas in a fast boat and aim directly for a small island.  You'll clear the entire island with little damage.  But if you jump out of the boat first, it will detonate as soon as it hits the beach.

---

Not sure how helpful this is, but I found it interesting to drive some vehicles over the waterfall at *Panau Falls Casino*.  It applies a moving force against you and whatever vehicle you're in, and it totalled my agency boat before reaching the bottom by bashing it against the cliff face.  Might give you a little more insight into how it works?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with the game, falls from large heights max out at a set amount of damage with added damage if you do not land right side up. This max damage is too high for motorcycles as they like to explode on landing. If you roll while landing you will cause extra damage to your vehicle, likely causing it to explode.

Really though I think you need to take the scientific approach here and test different vehicles with different durability from great heights. Frankly your jump is too small.

Go to the civilian airport with the vehicle you want to test. Follow the passenger jet, jump on top of your car and tether your vehicle to the plane. Quickly jump back in side your car and hold on tight!

Once you have reached a high enough altitude and you are over land press the tether button again to detach the tether to the plane and wait until impact.

**Edit**

Here we go

Comment: Fun fact: Tethering a car to a jet and then getting into it will cause the grappling hook to disconnect

Comment: @JoethePerson Actually no, no it wont. You had better try that again. Seriously, it is awesome fun.

Comment: I tried it on the passenger jets at Panau International with a car from the Black Market, it didnt work from there. I'll try it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe they have some sort of function that would take the type of car and the height to calculate the damage a certain height would cause. I also believe that it also depends on how the car hits the ground, usually the car takes more damage from the front than it does from the sides.

Comment: I am not talking about damage, I'm talking about it blowing up, like it would with a plane or motorcycle

Answer (score 0):

Yes definitely it will explode there is no doubt in that and this explosion happens because of some destruction.The truck damage can be calculated based on the height it falls.